# Sql not accepting values in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

php

```
 $dnumber = '9515551212';
 $device_id = 'f3847010927038970110923';
```

device is a text field
phnum (I have used bigint, text, varchar)  all give the same result.

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO devices(device, phnum) VALUES('$device_id', '$dnumber')");
```

the above query is TRUE but the value in phnum will be empty.

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO devices(device, phnum) VALUES('$device_id', $dnumber)");
```

the above query is FALSE, but it still inserts the record perfectly! I also get error 1064 near ")"  (I removed the quotes from $dnumber)

So why is the first saying it succeeded but didnt put anything there while second says it fails but it inserted it as I wanted it to?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I wouldn't use any `int` to store phone numbers; I'd go with a varchar

Comment: Add `mysql_error()`, like `mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

I think, there's something with incoming data. SQL works well.

I tried that query from php:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test(device_id, phnum) VALUES('$device_id', '$dnumber')";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

For the table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `phnum` int(30) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`phnum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4294967295 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It worked well without any warnings. From SQL client - the same, works well.